# How would I implement a Round Robin scheduling simulator?

Tags: c++, struct, scheduling, deque

Using a deque of structs that look like this:

```
struct{
    int ID;
    int arrivalTime;
    int burstTime;
};
```

How would I step through the deque of structs so that if the input where like this:

```
0 0 3
1 5 2
3 8 4
```

where each row is a struct's ID, arrivalTime, and burstTime respectively, I would be able to print out something like this:

```
Time 0 Process 0 is running
Time 2 Process 0 is running
Time 3 Processor is Idle
Time 5 Process 1 is running
Time 7 Processor is Idle
Time 8 Process 3 is running
Time 10 Process 3 is running
```

this output is assuming a time quantum of 2. Is there a way to do this with just one deque or would it be easier to create another deck as a FIFO queue to process this? I know I'll need an integer to keep track of how much time has elapsed, but other than that this problem is really stumping me. Its the idle time that throws me off. Any help in C++ code or even psuedocode would really help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain your question more. What did try and what you cant implement?

Answer (score 0):

> I know I'll need an integer to keep track of how much time has elapsed

I would start with three values - elapsed time, current process and next process. Your scheduling loop might look something like below. I've put the logic choosing next process to a standalone function for the sake of simplicity:

```
time = 0;
currentProcess = deque.end();
while(some processes remaining)
{
    nextProcess = getNextProcess(time, currentProcess, deque);

    if(nextProcess->arrivalTime > time)
    {
        // nothing to do now
        // advance time by smaller of quota or nextProcess->arrivalTime
    } else {
        // at least one process has work ready
        if(currentProcess != nextProcess)
        {
            // preemt currentProcess
            // start nextProcess
            // advance time by the smaller of quota or nextProcess->burstTime
            // reduce nextProcess->burstTime by the time advanced
        } else {
            // continue with current process for quota or its remaining burstTime
            // reduce its burstTime
        }
    }

    currentProcess = nextProcess;
}
```

Implementing `getNextProcess` depends on your priority criteria, a naive approach might look like this:

- You go through `deque` starting at position `currentProcess + 1`. When you hit the end, continue from beginning.
- Take note of the process with smallest `arrivalTime` that is greater than `time`. Lets call it `closestCandidate`
- If you find suitable process with `arrivalTime <= time` and `burstTime > 0`, return that
- If you hit `currentProcess` again, decide between `currentProcess` and `closestCandidate` which is better to process and return that.

One last thing to do is to effectively implement the looping condition. I will leave that for you to figure out.

NOTE: Im not sure if `deque` is the best container here, I would pobably use `forward_list` and delete the processes as they finish. You could do this in the deque too, but thats O(n) operation.